Comedy about two con-men and a policewoman that has them under surveillance
Can someone please help me out with this one movie?
It's a movie about two con-men, and one of them is the brains of the group, and the other one is stupid, and they somehow acquire a lot of cash from somewhere illegally, and also the smart guy starts dating a girl who pretends to be a high school teacher, but really is a cop and has them under surveillance, but later she falls in love with him. I also remember she has a white poodle.
It's a comedy, not very serious. The movie is either American or European. It is not a new movie (not after 2010 or something), but not too old either - in color, with decent cinematography.

It's unlikely, but may be Steal

It could be "A Piece of the Action" with Bill Cosby, Sidney Poitier and James Earl Jones from 1977
Bill Cosby and Sidney Poitier are two con-men who have never been caught but are discovered by a retired detective (James Earl Jones) who starts taking advantage of them, and forces them to work at an underprivledged school.  If they don't, Jone's character will get them arrested.
The problem is they get forced back in for one last height.
From what I remember, Sidney Poieter's character starts falling for one of the teachers.  He ends up telling her the truth about why he is working there, and work out a plan to get rid of the detective.

No, sorry, that's not it. The main characters in my movie are white. Thanks for trying though :D
